# How to solve this indefinite integral (similar integral solvable)?

Tags: integration

I am working on a problem and trying to evaluate an integral of the form:
$$\int \frac{(c+f^nx^n)^{1/n}}{d+x(c+f^nx^n)^{1/n}}dx$$

I tried manually and haven't been able to come up with a solution and also tried the https://www.integral-calculator.com/ solver, which I've had the best luck with before.

The integral:
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{c+f^2x^2}}{d+x\sqrt{c+f^2x^2}}dx$$
has a solution of the form:
$$\dfrac{c\ln\left(\left|\frac{2df^2x}{\sqrt{f^2x^2+c}}+\sqrt{4d^2f^2+c^2}+c\right|\right)+c\ln\left(\left|\frac{2df^2x}{\sqrt{f^2x^2+c}}+\sqrt{4d^2f^2+c^2}-c\right|\right)-c\ln\left(\left|\frac{2df^2x}{\sqrt{f^2x^2+c}}-\sqrt{4d^2f^2+c^2}+c\right|\right)-c\ln\left(\left|\frac{2df^2x}{\sqrt{f^2x^2+c}}-\sqrt{4d^2f^2+c^2}-c\right|\right)-c\ln\left(\left|2f^2x^2+\sqrt{4d^2f^2+c^2}+c\right|\right)+c\ln\left(\left|2f^2x^2-\sqrt{4d^2f^2+c^2}+c\right|\right)}{4\sqrt{4d^2f^2+c^2}}+\dfrac{-\ln\left(\left|\frac{cx}{\sqrt{f^2x^2+c}}+\frac{df^2x^2}{f^2x^2+c}-d\right|\right)+\ln\left(\left|\frac{cx}{\sqrt{f^2x^2+c}}-\frac{df^2x^2}{f^2x^2+c}+d\right|\right)+\ln\left(\left|x^2\cdot\left(f^2x^2+c\right)-d^2\right|\right)}{4}$$
which can be found by rationalizing the denominator and then using u substitution.

Let me know if y'all have any ideas, or if you think it isn't expressible in terms of standard functions.